# python function or module to calculate one of dependent variable

Tags: python

I'm new to python and beginning to use it as a data analysis tool.
Say, I have two equations describing the relationship between four variables a,b,c, and d:

```
f(a,b,c,d)=0
g(a,b,c,d)=0

(a = b*c^3; d = a/c^2 could be an example.)
```

I want to create a function (or module?) that calculates the unknown two parameters given two numbers, which can be any combination of a,b,c, and d.

It looks like I have to write six functions to account for all possible combinations anyway. Can I integrate them functions into one class? Can anybody give me a reference or example of such a program?

Comment: You could take a look at [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html)

Comment: all of the combinations of your variables is `6` ? (ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd)

Comment: Oh yes. It should be 6.